# Add nodes to binary search tree c++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am building a binary search tree. Now I am having a problem with adding a node to the tree.

```
void BinaryTree::add(int value, Node* node) {
    if(!node)
        node = new Node(value);
    else if(node->key < value)
        this->add(value, node->rightNode);
    else if(node->key > value)
        this->add(value, node->leftNode);
}
```

This code does not seem to work when I call:

```
BinaryTree test;
test.add(4, test.root);
test.add(1, test.root);
test.add(5, test.root);
test.add(2, test.root);
test.add(3, test.root);
test.add(7, test.root);
test.add(6, test.root);
```

After the first add call, the root of the tree 'test' is still empty.
How shall I change the code so that it will be updated when I call add and the node goes to the correct place of the tree?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You can pass the `Node *` by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `Node *` by value here:

```
void BinaryTree::add(int value, Node* node) {
```

One solution is to pass by reference instead:

```
void BinaryTree::add(int value, Node *& node) {
                                      ^
```

If you pass by value the function is just receiving a copy of the `Node *` and so any modification to it will not be reflected back in the calling code.

Also you might want to think about what happens when `value` is equal to the `key`.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question, when I pass the pointer by value, the copied pointer does not point the same object?

Comment: @Ra1nWarden Yes, it will point to the same object, so if you modify the object it points to those changes will be reflected but modifications to the pointer itself will not.

Comment: I see. Yea, I am assuming the keys are distinct for now.

Answer (score 0):

You recursively call the add function, but nowhere in there do I see you actually assigning leftNode or rightNode to the passed in node.

Comment: The leftNode or rightNode would be added in the base case of the next recursion - if the node parameter had been declared correctly